# Мерзкий - этимология

Tags: этимология

Мерзкий — значит, противный, отвратительный. А каково происхождение этого слова? Честно говоря, у меня даже идей нет.

Answer (score 3):

Заходите в гугл. Набираете "мерзкий этимология". Первый же ответ - Ваш. ;)

> Происходит от праслав. формы, от которой в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск. мьрзъкъ, ст.-слав. мръзъкъ (др.-греч. βδελυρός), русск. мерзкий, укр. мерзенний, сербохорв. мр̏зак, мр̏зка «противный, -ая», словенск. mŕzǝk, mŕzkа «отвратительный, -ая», чешск., словацк. mrzký «скверный, гадкий». Родственно мёрзнуть, мороз; ср.: алб. mardhem «дрожу от холода», marth м. «мороз». Ср. также знач. чешск. ostuditi «возбудить отвращение» (см. студить, стыд), нов.-в.-нем. Schauder «дрожь, озноб; ужас, отвращение». Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера; см. Список литературы.

Comment: Найти легко. Понять бывает трудно. Хорошо, когда не копируете словарь, а объясняете. Потому что много специальных знаков, сокращений.

Comment: Тогда и пишите, что не поняли. А когда "нет идей" - я Вам и  подкидываю идею, где найти.

Comment: Тогда, может, закроем форум, раз все у гугле и так есть?